# Use non-breaking spaces in sidebar banner links

Tags: bug, design

There’s a dialog sidebar with links to the About page, FAQ and meta. Unfortunately, the “FAQ” link is broken in half, resulting in an (1) unaesthetic and (2) slightly confusing visual.

[image: design bug]

This could be fixed easily by putting a non-breaking space between the text and the French quote.